# Shapefile incompatibility between ArcGIS Online and QGIS 3.4 for a point feature layer

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online-webmap

I created a hosted feature point layer ('Threatened Plant Locations') in an ArcGIS Online webmap, collected some data using Collector for GIS app on my iPad, synced data back to my ArcGIS Online webmap, exported (as .shp and GeoJSON files) and downloaded data to my PC and then imported .shp and GeoJSON files to my QGIS 3.4 project map. I noticed that the points in my QGIS map are up to 10 metres away from their collected 'true/actual' positions. The points are correctly placed in the ArcGIS Online webmap and when I uploaded the shapefile to ESRI support, they informed me that the points loaded correctly in ArcMap as well.

Note the point feature layer source data is in EPSG: 3857 WGS84 (ArcGIS Online/Collector data is always WGS84) as is the source CRS for the public imagery layer I am using as a basemap in QGIS (NSW LPI). The CRS I am using for my QGIS Project map is GDA94 MGA56 (EPSG:28356) as I want all layers rendered/displayed to this CRS. I thought this might be a projection issue but when I exported the shapefile in order to create a new reprojected shapefile (with WGS84 CRS) there was still no change in the point positions on my QGIS map.

There was a similar question asked a number of years ago but the only answer related to reprojecting shapefile which I have already tried. Not sure it is a projection issue?

Any there any ArcGIS Online/QGIS users out there?

Comment: This seems more like a datum shift issue, projecting incorrectly in QGIS (without datum transformation).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes probably a projection issue. I have created new QGIS project map and have brought in shp. file and basemap imagery both as EPSG: 3857 WGS 84 Pseudo Mercator. QGIS still projecting points incorrectly. New project map also has a defined CRS as 3857. Very strange.

Comment: Since someone tried the points in ArcMap, I suggest exporting the points from there into a 2nd shapefile and importing it into Qgis. Of course, not a workflow solution, but may help diagnose the shapefile import by eliminating AGOL.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but ESRI support have already informed me that my shp. file that i exported and downloaded from arcGIS online projected correctly in all ESRI GIS products so asking ESRI to export a second shapefile for import to QGIS will probably not assist in diagnosing the issue as there doesn't appear to be an export issue from AGOL (if there was a possible export issue then the data would not have projected correctly for ESRI support staff in their products). There must be a general incompatibility between ESRI arcGIS and QGIS. Thanks